# Creating and running parallel circuits in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit

I'm trying to create and run parallel execution using the instruction [here](https://medium.com/qiskit/qiskit-backends-what-they-are-and-how-to-work-with-them-fb66b3bd0463). However, when I implement it, it tells me that I shouldn't be using `compile` anymore since

> DeprecationWarning: qiskit.compile() is deprecated and will be removed in Qiskit Terra 0.9. Please use qiskit.compiler.transpile() to transform circuits and qiskit.compiler.assemble() to produce a runnable qobj.
>     DeprecationWarning)

So how do I go about doing this using the new modules? Thank you!

Here's the code in the link for creating parallel executions:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import Aer, compile
from qiskit.backends.jobstatus import JOB_FINAL_STATES

n_qubits = 5
qc_list = []
for i in range(n_qubits):
    qr = QuantumRegister(n_qubits)
    cr = ClassicalRegister(n_qubits)
    qc = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
    qc.x(qr[i])
    qc.measure(qr, cr)
    qc_list.append(qc)

backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
qobj_list = [compile(qc, backend) for qc in qc_list]
job_list = [backend.run(qobj) for qobj in qobj_list]

while job_list:
    for job in job_list:
        if job.status() in JOB_FINAL_STATES:
            job_list.remove(job)
            print(job.result().get_counts())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `compile` is deprecated in favor of `transpile` and `assemble`. For your code, using these two new functions would look something like this:

```
# Add to your import statements
from qiskit.compiler import transpile, assemble

# After creating qc_list
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
transpiled_circs = transpile(qc_list, backend=backend)
qobjs = assemble(transpiled_circs, backend=backend)
job_info = backend.run(qobjs)

# To get the results
for circ_index in range(len(transpiled_circs)):
    print(job_info.result().get_counts(transpiled_circs[circ_index]))
```

## About the code

`qc_list` is still a list of circuits. `transpiled_circs` is a list of transpiled circuits from `qc_list`. `qobjs` is a single qobj with information for each circuit in `transpiled_circs`. `job_info` is job that is returned from `backend.run(qobjs)` it is a single job object.

Since `job_info` is a single job, the results for each circuit are located `job_info.result().get_counts()`. You just need to provide `get_counts` with a circuit to return the specific results for that circuit. That is what the for loop provides.

## About transpile and assemble

`transpile` takes in a `QuantumCircuit` or list of `QuantumCircuits` and runs through certain `PassManagers` which optimize the circuit for the specific backend given. This can include rearranging gates, compressing sets of gates, deleting unnecessary gates, rearranging CX connections, etc. It returns a new circuit, or list of circuits

`assemble` takes in a `QuantumCircuit` of a list of `QuantumCircuits` and compresses them into a `qobj`

The source code for both functions can be found here: [transpile](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/compiler/transpile.py),  [assemble](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/compiler/assemble.py)