# How to parallelly run a quantum circuit on IBMQ?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I am trying to implement the following circuit [image]

and my code is

[image]

The above circuit has size 5 and depth 3. My question is, how can I run the circuit parallelly. I mean, the gate `circuit.cx(qr[0], qr[1])` and gate `circuit.cx(qr[2], qr[3])` will be run at the same time and the total running time is dominated by the depth.

I found a related question in [Creating and running parallel circuits in Qiskit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6697/creating-and-running-parallel-circuits-in-qiskit). However, in that question, the author tries to run several independent experiments rather than run the gates in a circuit parallelly.

Comment: The ability to run the gates in parallel is up to the device. There could be technical reasons as to why this could be bad, eg noise in simultaneous gates. That said, all IBM Quantum devices run in parallel when possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qiskit implements a transpiler which optimizes the circuits that you provide. This means it modifies the circuit so that it can be run on the backend and also optimizes it so that anything that can possibly be run in parallel is done so. To run with the maximum level of optimization you can run `execute(circuit, optimization_level=3)`. There is more information about the transpiler [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/fundamentals/5_using_the_transpiler.ipynb).

If you would like even finer control of when things are executed you can create a Pulse Schedule. There is more information about this [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-iqx-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/advanced/terra/5_pulse_schedules.ipynb).

Comment: The current tutorial appears to be here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/circuits_advanced/04_transpiler_passes_and_passmanager.ipynb
But it makes no mention of parallelizing quantum circuits. There's also no documented transpiler pass that attempts it: https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/transpiler_passes.html
It looks like they don't currently try to parallelize, unless they do so after a job is submitted? I notice .draw function shows gates in parallel even when the openqasm circuit is clearly not in parallel, which suggests maybe they do parallelize.